# telerik winforms linq to radgridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, telerik

I want to learn Telerik. But I am too newbee.
I have a table named `"makale"` and it has 7 column named, `"no"`, `"ad"`, `"yazar"`, `"kunye"`, `"ders"`, `"olusturma"`, `"guncelleme"`
I created a Link to SQL class and I managed to get data like this:

```
LinqtoSQLDataContext oc = new LinqtoSQLDataContext ();
var all = oc.makales;
```

Now I want to fetch this table to Telerik Radgridview. When I use `Gridview1.DataSource = all;` code, it fetches all columns. But I want to fetch only `"ad"`, `"yazar"`, `"kunye"` and `"ders"` columns. And I want to change gridview columns' text like `"AD"`, `"YAZAR"`, `"KÜNYE"`, `"ŞİŞKO"`. But when I use `Gridview1.DataSource = all;` code, gridview columns' text are same as table's columns' name. And I want to set columns' width too.

Could you help me, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `RadGridView` generating columns automatically based on the `DataSource` (`Gridview1.DataSource = all;`)

My advise  generate columns by yourself. [Telerik. Generating columns](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-generating-columns.html)

Set `MyRadGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;`

Then create column

```
GridViewTextBoxColumn yazarColumn = new GridViewTextBoxColumn("UniqueNameYazarColumn");
yazarColumn.Name = "UniqueNameYazarColumn";
textBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Your header";
textBoxColumn.FieldName = "yazar"; //Field is name of the bounded property of source
//add column to the grid
MyRadGridView.Columns.Add(yazarColumn);
```

Telerik have good enough documentation and basic examples for Winforms controls
[Telerik UI Winforms.. GridView](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problems you have 2 ways to do it.
First you can do the "Gridview1.DataSource = all" and then edit the columns that it has generated, or you can previously set up all columns you want to see and then use the Datasource.

The first one is the easy way to begin with. 
After you link using "Gridview1.DataSource = all"
you said that all columns are "no", "ad", "yazar", "kunye", "ders", "olusturma", "guncelleme" but only "ad", "yazar", "kunye" and "ders"  should appear.

You need to work all the columns like this >>>>

if you want to edit for the names use this:
this.Gridview1.Columns["put_the_name_of_the_column_here"].HeaderText = "Put the name you want to appear on the screen top of the grid here";
this.Gridview1.Columns["put_the_name_of_the_column_here"].IsVisible = false;

if you want the columns not to appear:
this.Gridview1.Columns["put_the_name_of_the_column_here"].IsVisible = false;

Example:

this.Gridview1.Columns["no"].IsVisible = false;

this.Gridview1.Columns["ad"].HeaderText = "AD";
this.Gridview1.Columns["ad"].IsVisible = true;

this.Gridview1.Columns["yazar"].HeaderText = "YAZAR";
this.Gridview1.Columns["yazar"].IsVisible = true;

and so on.....

I´ve working with Telerik´s for Winforms for 5 years now.... I hope I could help...

See ya..